# Put html table data in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Hey guy's I am trying to send table information to google spreadsheet.

I have tried:

[This worked (but i need table data instead of input)](http://railsrescue.com/blog/2015-05-28-step-by-step-setup-to-send-form-data-to-google-sheets/)

Is there a way to fix it without using google-script.
just pure javascript ?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Wick</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jeff</td>
    <td>AndersOn</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>


    <button type="submit" onclick="test()" >Verzenden</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to put the tables in array [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206569/put-table-in-array)

After that you have to make 2 functions 
1 that creates an spreadsheet and 1 that writes the value in it.

You can find many information at the link that MR.Rebot shared

I used this (after putting

```
var params = {
    "range":"Sheet!A1",
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": [],   
}
('POST', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+SheetID+':batchUpdate')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Sheets API:

> The Google Sheets API lets you read and modify any aspect of a spreadsheet. Spreadsheets have many settings that let you craft beautiful and functional sheets, so the API has many settings too. The API offers two main ways to interact with the spreadsheet:
>
> - Reading/writing cell values only (via the [spreadsheets.values collection](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values)).
> - Reading/writing any aspect of the spreadsheet (via the [spreadsheets collection](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets)).

There is a [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) that makes requests to the Google Sheets API. You can use this to familiarize yourself with the functions and code implementation.

Hope this helps.